# xvfb with tkinter on colab

Tags: tkinter, google-colaboratory, xvfb

I use a concealer in a colab and it doesn't work
I tried using xvfb
The gear in the colab works for a long time and no screen comes out
How to change the settings in xvfb
A screen with a technology destination will appear
Or another solution: How to take a screenshot of your computer without showing a screen
Save it in the COLAB directory
I am using modern Linux Mint and Colab latest version